# Ergodic system has a.e. dense orbits

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

One more question:

Let $X$ be a metric space with probability measure $\mu$ and $T\colon X \to X$ ergodic.

$\Rightarrow f$.a.e. $x$ the orbit  $O_x=\{T^n(x) : n \in Z\}$ is dense in $X$.

So I have to show that the set $B$ containing all x for which $O_x$ is not dense has measure 0. Obviously $B$ is $T$-invariant, since $O_x$ is $T$-invariant for all $x$.
A set is dense in $X$, if it has nonempty intersection with all open sets of $X$ (maybe I can use here the special structure of $X$ as a metric space?). Poincare's theorem is given as a hint.
Since the system is ergodic I know that $\mu(B)$ and $\mu(B^c) \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: If $\mu$ is the Dirac mass at a fixed point of $T$, this is false. Are you sure you don't have any additional information about $\mu$ ?

Comment: sorry, $\mu$ is a Borel-probability measure

Comment: a Dirac mass is a Borel probability measure ... As Siming Tu pointed out in his answer, you need additionnal assumptions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claimed property does not hold in general, even for $X$ compact metric (which would have a countable base). Just take $T$ to be a rational rotation of the circle, i.e. $T(x)=x+p/q \mod 1$ (with $p,q\in\mathbb N$), then clearly all points are periodic and the measure of the set of points having dense orbits is zero (because there are none at all). Here an ergodic measure would be the uniform measure in a single periodic orbit.

Denseness of orbits is a topological property, so you would either need an additional topological assumption or something stronger on the measure to conclude this.

Poincare's recurrence theorem only gives that almost every point returns to a neighborhood of itself (and this happens infinitely many times along the forward orbit). By the way Poincare recurrence also only holds for compact metric spaces. Think of a transformation like $x\mapsto x+1$ on the (non-compact) real line and take Lebesgue measure. No point returns close to itself, the system is not recurrent.

Comment: Mhm sounds like there different versions of Poincares recurrence…we proved it for finite measures and the lebegue measure on R is not finite

Comment: I don't understand your counter example…the rational rotation together with the Lebegue measure is not ergodic, what you mean with "uniform measure in a single periodic orbit"?

Comment: @crank: For a Borel probability measure it does not not to be a Lebegue measure. "uniform measure in a single periodic orbit" means that every point in the orbit has the same measure (note that the orbit is finite). So you may need something like that open set has positive measure.

Comment: okay thank you guys…I have the tutorial on wednesday if someone is interested I post the solution then

Answer (score 7):

If the space has a countable basis and for the measure $\mu$ any open set has positive measure we can have this result as proved below, in other case there may be counterexample.

Since $X$ is a metric space, we can find countable basis $\{U_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$. Not that if for $x\in X$, the orbit of $x$ is not dense, then there exists some $U_j$ such that $\{T^n(x):n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\cap U_j=\emptyset$ so $$x\in A_j=X-\cup_{i=0}^{\infty}T^{-i}U_j.$$ So the set of $X$ such that the orbit of $x$ is not dense is contained in the set $\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j$. Note that $A_j$ is $T$-invariant and has a empty intersection with $U_j$ so $\mu(A_j)=0$ since $U_j$ has positive measure. And so $\mu(\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j)=0$ and the proof is completed.

Comment: Are you sure X has a countable basis? In wikipedia it says that for a metric space you just have a countable local basis for every point in X

Comment: Sorry，you are right the space may not have a countable basis. This proof may work for when the space has a countable basis, I;m trying to think how to work for general case. And sorry that I missed a "$T^{-i}$" in the proof.