# ergodic system has dense orbits a.e., continuity of T

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

My question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990229/ergodic-system-has-a-e-dense-orbits), i.e. under which conditions we have that $\mu$-a.e. point has a dense orbit in a dynamical system $(X,T)$ with measure $\mu$. I am confused about the assumptions. In at least two textbooks ([An Introduction to Ergodic Theory](https://books.google.at/books?id=eCoufOp7ONMC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=ergodicity%20implies%20dense%20orbits&source=bl&ots=uMWUUHZ-RS&sig=G6_nXSuRYWn13Zt0v5974QklJhU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWjMylmJncAhWRr6QKHXBBBI0Q6AEIhQEwBw#v=onepage&q=ergodicity%20implies%20dense%20orbits&f=false), p.29; [Introduction to Dynamical Systems](ftp://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/P/PD/Brin%20M.,%20Stuck%20G.%20Introduction%20to%20dynamical%20systems%20(CUP,%202002)(ISBN%200521808413)(O)(254s)_PD_.pdf), p.76)  I read that T must be continuous, but I don't see where the continuity of $T$ comes in.

The statement:
Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $T:X\rightarrow X$ a continuous map and $\mu$ a $T$-invariant borel measure on X. If $T$ is ergodic, then the orbit of $\mu$-a.e. point is dense in $X$.

This can be proven by showing that the set of all points whose forwars orbit visit every element of an open basis has full measure.
Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a countable open basis for X, then for every $U_i$, $\mu(U_i)>0$ and $T^{-1}(\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}T^{-k}U_i)\subseteq \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}T^{-k}U_i$. Since $T$ is measure-preserving and ergodic, it follows that $\mu(\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}T^{-k}U_i)$ has full measure in X.

Where exactly is the continuity of $T$ used?
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: You forgot to mention the assumption that $\mu(U)>0$ for any open $U$, see MHS's answer to the linked question.

Comment: sorry, yes, I forgot to mention that I consider elements from supp$\mu$

Comment: It also appears to me that continuity is not actually used in the proof and any measurable map $T$ will do as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I have the answer: The proof uses continuity of $T$ in the countable union of $T^{-k}U_i$. As @user539887 pointed out, we need the assumption that $\mu(U)>0$ for any open $U$, equivalently $U$ is in the support of $\mu$. Since the preimage of a open set is open iff $T$ is continuous, the set $\bigcup T^{-k}U_i$ is open and has therefore full measure.

Comment: As $\mu$ is an invariant *Borel* measure and $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation, for any open $U$ there holds $\mu(T^{-1}(U))=\mu(U)$.