# Ergodic Lie subsemigroups have a.e. dense orbits in the homogenous quotient space.

Tags: lie-groups, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

There is a very general fact from a paper I am reading which I don't know the proof:

Let $X=G/\Gamma$, where $G$ is a Lie group and $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $G$. Let $\mu$ be a $G$-invariant probability measure on $X$. For a subsemigroup $F$ of $G$ which acts on $X$ ergodically, let

$$S:=\{x \in X: F.x ~\text{not dense in}~ X\}$$

then $S$ is a $\mu$-null set.

If $F$ is a group then I know a proof by mimicking the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/990266/185631) by putting $S$ in a countable union of null sets.

I wonder how to prove this fact in general or it follows from some ergodic theorems?

Source (first page of)

https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.14065

Comment: From a quick look, it seems like that linked proof applies to the semigroup $\{1,T,T^2,T^3,\dots\},$ and you could adapt it by replacing $\cup_{i=0}^\infty T^{-i}U_j$ by $\cup_{g\in F}g^{-1}U_j.$ How would $F$ being a group help?